# What is the best way for interacting between Components in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to intercept user activity from a child component and then update the state of one of its siblings.
E.g.

```
 -RootApp
 --Child1 (has user interaction e.g. onClick)
 --Child2 (needs data from Child1 to update state)
```

My solution (which I find rather weird) is I have a callback passed to **Child1** from **RootApp**. When the user does **onClick** on **Child1** the callback is called. The callback in **RootApp** then updates the props defined for **Child2**. **Child2** is re-rendered.

Am I doing this right?

Comment: Yep, the standard way for parent components to update child components is by passing a callback to child views. So in your case `Child1` needs to tell `RootApp` to change its state when some interaction occurs in `Child1`. Pass that state from `RootApp` to `Child2` and `Child2` will rerender whenever its props for that state changes

Comment: Thanks very much. Glad to see I was on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to trekforever for confirming. Callbacks are the way for passing states.

This is what I do (as in question):

```
-RootApp
 --Child1 (has user interaction e.g. onClick)
 --Child2 (needs data from Child1 to update state)
```

Have a callback passed to Child1 from RootApp. When the user does onClick on Child1 the callback is called. The callback in RootApp then updates the props defined for Child2. Child2 is re-rendered.

Answer (score 4):

Callback are the way to go but they may become very cumbersome when you need to introduce a component between the root and the child, or when you need to refactor your app and restructure the UI. You may look at [Morearty.js](https://github.com/moreartyjs/moreartyjs) which decouples components using single immutable state data structure. So, in child's onClick you just update the state and all other components which depend on that state section will be re-rendered automatically. See the introduction and API docs for more details.

Of course you still need callbacks for many valid cases but many of them are elliminated.

Comment: Brilliant thanks! Certainly true that if I want to stick a new component between existing components it's going to get seriously messy!!